# Logic boolean algebra problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

so I have to prove that these equations :
[image]

are equivalent?

Comment: What did you try? You can try to simplify one expression, or both, or make truth table.

Comment: Well a truth table is too much work for something like this, I want to do them using equivalent transformations, I tried simplifying them but that didn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example to get to know all boolean operators and to practice
operator precedence.

I translated both expressions into boolean `C#` expressions:

```
u = !!(x || !y) || !(!x && z) || (!(!x && (y == z)) || (!(x && y) != z));
v = !((!x || y) && !(x || (y && !z))) || !(y && z);
```

The translation is not unique. It assumes certain operator priorities.

To do the translation, the following operators have to be taken into account:

[image: translation of boolean operators into C# expressions]

When I run these expressions in a home-grown program, I get the following truth table:

[image: truth table]

This shows that both expressions are equivalent.

May be, that my assumptions are not true and the result should be a tautology for both expressions (all rows in the truth table have $1$ as result). This could lead to an equivalence proof: Show that both expressions are in fact tautologies.